# Can't install bower package from private git repo

Tags: git, bower, bower-install

I've got private repo. For example if i'll try to clone it git will ask me my username and password. 
Now i've created bower package and push it to my repo. When I try to install it I see this error:

```
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'http://tfs.mysite.ru:8080': Invalid argument
```

How can i solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue under win7. Somehow doing bower install from Git-Cmd app did the job, i was asked for credentials and then it managed to download dep from git repo.

Answer (score 0):

If we are installing private packager then it must for username and password.So somehow we have to give username and possible options are -

- If gitbash is popup enabled it will ask for username and password itself.
- Else you need to configure gitbash to allow popups.
- You can either provide username in the url itself as it worked for me

"ocinfra": "https://**sranka2**@github.myorganization.com/insurance/OcInfra.git#1.0.5"